# Authentification wi-fi with my Android?

Tags: connection-issues, usb-connection-mode, android-versions

I have an Hisense L675, Android version 6.0.
I haven't Wi-fi connection at home YET and I use my USB pendrive to my PC HP 15-AY094NL. Sometimes I would like to connect it and use it like Wi-fi with Hisense L675. But it doesn't work. I tryed everything for example turn off the mobile phone or my computer but I don't know what to do.

Comment: What type of pendrive is it e.g Sandisk etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that that there is a way to connect your mobile phone to your PC via USB to use internet, but I don't know a way like Wi-fi, there are some apps that probably can do it but I think you have to pay. Look at this [link](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-connect-my-android-phone-to-the-internet-through-my-laptop) and say me if I helped you